# ¿Como reducir el espacio y centrar en HTML con boostrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Amigos quisiera saber como puedo reducir el tamaño de mis botones e imagen de una forma global utilizando algún tipo de container, yo agregue un container sencillo pero como ven en la imagen eso es lo máximo que se reduce o encoge.

He visto que lo hacen modificando las rejillas pero quisiera saber si se puede hacer modificando el conteiner que tengo.

En la imagen coloque unas flechas indicando lo poco que se redujo con el container.

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Crediservir</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/css/img.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/estilosB.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table-responsive col-sm-12">
      <div id="img"><img class="centrado" src="../crediservir/bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/img/logo_index.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Imagen responsive"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <form action="controlador/control.php" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user">DOCUMENTO</label>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Ingresar usuario" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clave">CONTRASEÑA</label>
            <input type="password" name="clave" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
          </div>
          <?php
            if(isset($_GET["fallo"]) && $_GET["fallo"] == 'true')
            {
              echo "<div style='color:red'>Usuario o contraseña no coinciden,por favor verifique</div>";
            }
          ?>
          <input class="btn btn-i" type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="ENTRAR" />
          <input name="opcion" type="hidden" id="opcion" value="1" />
          <input class="btn btn-i" type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="CREAR CUENTA" />
          <input name="opcion" type="hidden" id="opcion" value="1" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin tocar el CSS, no, no es posible. Lo mejor que podrías hacer es agregar junto al container otra clase, y a esa darle un max-width.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya estuve viendo unos videos y si es así como dices.